# How to get Image from its native path?

Tags: iphone, image, file, titanium

I have store native path of image file to database. Now I need to display that image. For this I am using

```
imageView.image = Titanium.Filesystem.getfile(rows.fieldByName('path'));
```

But no effect.
it is giving error as

```
[ERROR] invalid image type. expected either TiBlob or TiFile, was: NSNull in -[TiUIImageView setImage_:] (TiUIImageView.m:679)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: set path.extension where extension is anything you use ex:png,jpg etc

Comment: Alert the path and see if it is correct. and also, hard code that db path and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it was because the database value you are returning is a string and not the actual image. Doesn't work like specifying an image path for the web. Try this:

```
var img_src = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(rows.fieldByName('path'));
var img = img_src.read();
imageView.image = img;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give native path in image attribute

`var u_image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image: rows.fieldByName('path'),
    top:10,
    left:10,
    height:20,
    width:20
});`

This may help you!!!